# 2D vector sort unwanted result

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, vector

I am trying to sort 2D vector. Not the elements, but only move the columns not the row elements. In my vector I kept the first place for the index of the columns so I know the original column number even when I sort the 2D array. So I wrote this code:

```
   // Sorting the rows.
   sort(numberlist[i].begin(), numberlist[i].end());

   // Adding the indexes.
   for(int e = 0; e < boxnum; e++)
   {
       numberlist[e][0] = e + 1;
   }

   //Sorting the columns.
   sort(numberlist.begin(), numberlist.end(), [](const vector<int>& a,
                                                 const vector<int>& b){
                                                 return a < b; });
```

My input to the program:

```
3 7
8 10
5 2
9 11
21 18
```

I was expecting this result:

```
3 2 5
1 3 7
2 8 10
4 9 11
5 18 21
```

I am getting this output:

```
1 3 7
2 8 10
3 2 5
4 9 11
5 18 21
```

Very unexpected. The indexes are weirdly increment by 1 even though they are sorted (The columns).

I tried setting the index like this:

```
   // Adding the indexes.
   for(int e = 0; e < boxnum; e++)
   {
       numberlist[e][0] = e + 104;
   }
```

Yet it increments by one in a weird way:

```
104 3 7
105 8 10
106 2 5
107 9 11
108 18 21
107 106 105 104
```

Can you guys help me out please? I really need this.

Comment: `sort(numberlist[i].begin(), numberlist[i].end());` where does the `i` come from in this statement? You need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's also not really clear at all from your expected input and output what kind of sorting you're trying to do, as it seems you're also transforming the data in some way (adding an additional column, with seemingly arbitrary values in it), and your process is poorly described.

Answer (score 0):

The first sort, sorts the columns of each row (I assume you each row starts with the element 0 or that each row has 0 as one of it's elements). Then you replace the first element of each row with an incrementing number. The lambda function in the second sort is comparing vectors starting with the first column instead of starting with the second column.

I created an example that more closely matches your description. It sorts a vector of iterators to the "rows" of a 2d vector (vector of vectors without the first column being an index). The columns of the 2d vector are sorted first, then the vector of iterators to the "rows" is sorted without actually sorting the rows of the 2d vector (the 2d vector could be sorted directly if this was wanted).

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

#define rows 5
#define columns 7

void displayvir(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator> &vir,
                std::vector<std::vector<int>> &vv)
{
std::vector<int>::iterator ic;
std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator ir;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < vir.size(); i++){
        ir = vir[i];
        std::cout << std::setw(3) << ir - vv.begin() << ':';
        for (ic = ir->begin(); ic < ir->end(); ic++){
            std::cout << std::setw(3) << *ic;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    // create vector of vectors (2d vector)
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> vv(rows, std::vector<int>(columns));
    // create iterator to column
    std::vector<int>::iterator ic;
    // create iterator to row
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator ir;
    // create vector of iterators to row
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator> vir(rows);
    // initialize vv and vir
    for(ir = vv.begin(); ir < vv.end(); ir++){
        vir[ir-vv.begin()] = ir;
        for(ic = ir->begin(); ic < ir->end(); ic++){
            *ic = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
    displayvir(vir, vv);
    // Sort columns in each row
    for (ir = vv.begin(); ir < vv.end(); ir++)
        std::sort(ir->begin(), ir->end());
    displayvir(vir, vv);
    // Sort vir
    std::sort(vir.begin(), vir.end(),
        []( const std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator &a,
            const std::vector<std::vector<int>>::iterator &b)
            {return(*a < *b);});
    displayvir(vir, vv);
    return 0;
}
```

C version:

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define rows 5
#define columns 7

void displayapr(int (*apr[rows])[columns], int a2d[rows][columns])
{
size_t i, j;
    printf("\n");
    for(j = 0; j < rows; j++){
        printf("%3d: ", apr[j]-a2d);
        for(i = 0; i < columns; i++){
            printf("%3d", (*apr[j])[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int compareint(const int *pa, const int *pb)
{
    return(memcmp(pa, pb, sizeof(int)));
}

int comparerows(const int (**ppr0)[columns], const int (**ppr1)[columns])
{
const int *p0 = **ppr0;
const int *p1 = **ppr1;
size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < columns; i++)
        if(p0[i] != p1[i])
            return p0[i] - p1[i];
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
int a2d[rows][columns];         /* 2d array */
int (*apr[rows])[columns];      /* array of ptrs to rows */
size_t i, j;

    /* init a2d, apr */
    for(j = 0; j < rows; j ++){
        apr[j] = &a2d[j];
        for(i = 0; i < columns; i++){
            a2d[j][i] = rand() % 10;
        }
    }
    displayapr(apr, a2d);
    /* Sort columns in each row of a2d */
    for(j = 0; j < rows; j ++)
        qsort(apr[j], columns, sizeof(int), compareint);
    displayapr(apr, a2d);
    /* Sort apr */
    qsort(apr, rows, sizeof(int *), comparerows);
    displayapr(apr, a2d);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thannks man! I am not a pro..So your code is bit confusing to me...Can you come up with simpler one.

Comment: @Boomrang - (note vv is v v, vector to vector, not the letter w, and iterators are essentially pointers) vir is a vector of iterators to rows in vv {iterator to row 0, iterator to row 1, ... iterator to row rows-1}. The expression (ir-vv.begin()) converts an iterator to row in vv into a normal index, {0, 1, ... rows-1}. This could be redone with c type code, using a c type 2d array, and pointers to integers and/or pointers to rows.

Comment: Thanks man! Appreciate it man...But can help me out turning it to C type one..If that is not a problem for you..

Comment: @Boomrang - I added a C version. The reason for using vir in the C++ example and apr in the C example is that the elements of the array being sorted need to be pointers to the 2d vector or array. An alternative would be to sort an array of indexes to the rows of the 2d array, but the compare parameters wouldn't have any pointers to the 2d array, requiring a global array for the C version, or a class that included the 2d array and a compare function operator (functor) for the C++ version.